# when i use jekyll template {% if page.title == {{ category | first }} %} get false

Tags: templates, jekyll, liquid

I show `page.title` and `{{ category | first }}` find is equal, but `{% if page.title == {{ category | first }} %}` is `false`. This is my code:

```
<li class=" {% if page.title == {{ category | first }} %} active {% endif %}">
```

Is any thing wrong in the syntax?

My complete code is:

```
{% for category in site.categories %}
    <li class=" {% if page.title == {{ category | first }} %} active {% endif %}">
    <a href="{{ site.baseurl }}/{{ category | first }}" title="{{ category | first }}">
        {% translate posts.{{ category | first }} %}
    </a>
    </li>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should refer to the first category by using `category[0]`. Nesting liquid does not work.

```
{% for category in site.categories %} 
  <li class="{% if page.title == category[0] %} active {% endif %}"> 
    <a href="{{ site.baseurl }}/{{ category | first }}" title="{{ category | first }}">
      {% translate posts.category[0] %}
    </a>
  </li>
{% endfor %}
```

Although I am not really sure what you are trying to achieve here...

Comment: thanks.
you are correct
because I write
```
 {% for category in site.categories %}
 {% capture currentCategory %}{{ category | first }}{% endcapture %}
 <li class="{% if page.title == currentCategory %}active{% endif %}">
```
also solve problem
(plsese ignore why code no have a newline because I am not familar with markdown)

Answer (score 0):

I want to have a summary

thanks for up answer. when no answer I solve use this code

````
``` 
{% for category in site.categories %}
  {% capture currentCategory %}{{ category | first }}{% endcapture %} 
<li class="{% if page.title == currentCategory %}active{% endif %}">
{% endfor %}
```
````

when I see up answer I know my answer is not good

also I realize why I first is fasle

I guess {{}} maybe only use in html tags when use in {{ xxxx }} just write variable name because in {} inner just like in template javescript